# Add two instances of a constructor using "+" operator

Tags: c#, constructor, operator-overloading

Please I need help here!
I created a constructor with 3 overloads in a class in C#
One of of the constructors takes a char[] array argument.

Two instances of the constructor are:
Constructor C1 = new Constructor();
Constructor C2 = new Constructor(char[] arr)

Here's the problem now:
Constructor C3 = C1 + C2

I get error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char[]' and 'char[]'

Here's what i tried:

```
public class Constructor
{ 
#region(fields)
        char _myChar;
        public char[] _myCharArray; 
 #endregion

 #region(Constructors)
        public Constructor() { }

        public Constructor(char[] arr) 
            : this()
        { 
            this._myCharArray = arr;
        }

        public Constructor (char a)
            : this()
        {
            this._myChar = a;
        }
 #endregion


 #region(Methods)
        
        public void Write() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_myCharArray);
        }
        #endregion

 #region(Operators)
        public static Constructor operator +(Constructor C1, Constructor C2)
        {
            Constructor C3 = new Constructor();
            C3._myCharArray = C1._myCharArray + C2._myCharArray;
            return C3;
        }
 #endregion

}

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
  Constructor C1 = new Constructors();
            Console.Write("Should print nothing: "); C1.Write(); Console.WriteLine();
            
            char[] a = { 'M', 'y', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e' };
            Constructor C2 = new Constructor(a);
            Console.Write("Should print 'My name': "); C2.Write(); Console.WriteLine(); 
            
            Constructor C3 = C1 + C2;
            Console.Write("Should print 'My name': "); C3.Write(); Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by adding two char arrays? This is what the compiler wants to know. Maybe you want to concatthearrays?

Comment: @Clemens, this s actually an assignment to check prove the possibility of such overloading. It's an academic work

Comment: Are you looking for `s3._myCharArray = s1._myCharArray.Concat(s2._myCharArray).ToArray();` or alike?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, that's what is to be achieved at the end. However, I ought to concat two instances of a constructor with 3 overloads. C1 is the parameterless while C2 takes a char[] arr argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs on this line in your `+` operator overload:

```cs
s3._myCharArray = s1._myCharArray + s2._myCharArray;
```

Even though you can overload `+` operator for your user-defined `Constructor` class, you cannot overload operators of built-in types of C#. Due to this, you need to combine these two arrays into one like (as suggested in comments by Dmitry Bychenko)

```cs
s3._myCharArray = s1._myCharArray.Concat(s2._myCharArray).ToArray();
```

This is the most simple one, but you can also use other methods for combining char arrays. For example:

```cs
s3._myCharArray = new T[s1._myCharArray.Length + s2._myCharArray.Length];
s1._myCharArray.CopyTo(result, 0);
s2._myCharArray.CopyTo(result, s1._myCharArray.Length);
```

Whichever method you choose, after doing this, you can concatenate your `Constructor` objects just like the way you want:

```cs
Constructor C3 = C1 + C2;
```

You will see your desired output after that in the console:

```
My name
```

More info about operator overloading in C# can be found here: [Operator overloading (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading)

At the end, your whole `Constructor` class would be something like this:

```cs
public class Constructor
{
    #region(fields)
    public char[] _myCharArray;
    #endregion

    #region(Constructors)
    public Constructor()
    {
        this._myCharArray = new char[0];
    }

    public Constructor(char[] arr)
        : this()
    {
        this._myCharArray = arr;
    }

    public Constructor(char a)
        : this()
    {
        this._myCharArray = new char[1] { a };
    }
    #endregion

    #region(Methods)
    public void Write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_myCharArray);
    }
    #endregion

    #region(Operators)
    public static Constructor operator +(Constructor c1, Constructor c2)
    {
        Constructor c3 = new Constructor();
        c3._myCharArray = c1._myCharArray.Concat(c2._myCharArray).ToArray();
        return c3;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance, I new to c#! I tried both methods. The first suggestion threw an Unhandled Exception: "VALUE CANNOT BE NULL". The second suggestion threw some errors: 1. The type or namespace T could not be found... 2.Cannot implicitly convert type T[] to char[]. 3. The name 'result' does not exist in the current context. The last error is expected; what is suppose to be that variable 'result'?

Comment: I can address the "value cannot be null" problem. In the `public Constructor() { }`, you don't assign anything into `_myCharArray`, so in current situation, it is null. You can assign it to a new empty char array, and the error will go away. Like this: `public Constructor() { _myCharArray = new char[0]; }`

Comment: @Chuks In addition, I suggest you to use a char array for all of your constructors including the third one which takes only a char. This will be more close to the behavior you desire. I edited my answer to include the code of your `Constructor` class. That will work without you changing anything in your `Main` method.

Comment: Thanks a bunch; Big thanks once again. You saved a soul! Worked like majic

Comment: pls, there is one more request on the same issue I'd love to make. Suppose i need to get: 1. "Constructor C5 = C4.ToLower();".  where C4 and C5 are instances of the class Constructor. Please this is not an act of ingratitude, it's a man in need. thanks

Comment: @Chuks this one is a different question. You should open a new question for that according to Stack Overflow guidelines.